# how to add include path in a gn file

Tags: header-files, ninja

I have a list of source file that i have included in source variable. I have included all header files required in include variable. So my gn file looks something like this.

```
shared_library(mylib) {
   sources = [
      <all the source files>
   ]
   includes = [
      <all the header files>
   ]
}
```

And then i run `ninja -C out/Output <mytarget>`. But it gives me this error: `You set the variable "includes" here and it was unused before it went out of scope.`

Now here in the source files, the headers are wrapped in `<>` and if i change to `""`, all the errors are resolved but there must be a way to define include paths so that all the dependencies are resolved automatically.